# specify a thumbnail and replace a video using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

Can I specify a image thumbnail (or a specific frame during the video) to be used for my video using YouTube API? Also, can we "replace" a video using YouTubes API?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a thumbnail: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set

You cannot "replace" a video.  The update method only supports updating metadata, not the video itself: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update